# Conditional expression parse error on an elaborated-type-specifier inside a new-expression

Tags: c++, parsing, gcc, visual-c++, clang

Consider the following C++ code:

```
struct A {};
struct A* b = (1 == 1) ? new struct A : new struct A;
```

MSVC accepts this, but GCC and Clang do not. **I would like to understand which is correct according to the standard, and why.**

The error that Clang gives is:

```
test.cpp:2:37: error: redefinition of 'A'
struct A* b = (1 == 1) ? new struct A : new struct A;
                                    ^
test.cpp:1:8: note: previous definition is here
struct A {};
       ^
test.cpp:2:37: error: '(anonymous struct at test.cpp:2:37)' cannot be defined in a type specifier
struct A* b = (1 == 1) ? new struct A : new struct A;
                                    ^
test.cpp:2:41: error: expected class name
struct A* b = (1 == 1) ? new struct A : new struct A;
                                        ^
test.cpp:2:53: error: expected '{' after base class list
struct A* b = (1 == 1) ? new struct A : new struct A;
                                                    ^
test.cpp:2:53: error: expected ':'
struct A* b = (1 == 1) ? new struct A : new struct A;
                                                    ^
                                                    :
test.cpp:2:24: note: to match this '?'
struct A* b = (1 == 1) ? new struct A : new struct A;
                       ^
test.cpp:2:53: error: expected expression
struct A* b = (1 == 1) ? new struct A : new struct A;
                                                    ^
```

This suggests to me that clang is trying to parse the tokens `struct A :` as a *class-specifier*, with the colon introducing a *base-clause*, and then bails when that parse fails.

However, I don't understand why it would try to parse a *class-specifier* at all. Looking at the grammar for *new-expression* in the  [latest draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4687.pdf), it uses a *new-type-id* grammar production, which uses *type-specifier-seq*, which uses *type-specifier*. However, *class-specifier* is **not** one of the alternatives for *type-specifier* - it only appears as an alternative for *defining-type-specifier*. On the other hand, *elaborated-type-specifier* **is** one of the alternatives for *type-specifier*, and would give us the intended parse here.

Comment: C++ does not use C's tagged namespaces. Out of curiosity, do you get the same result when you drop the `struct`, like in `new struct A`? That is, does just `new A` trigger it?

Comment: @jww It would be one lousy compiler if it does. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/Ueodme)

Comment: @jww: `new A` works fine (and it's easy to see why: `A` is now just a *named-type-specifier*, there is no possibility of it being the start of a *elaborated-type-specifier* or *class-specifier*).

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: The wording is actually confusing. It says [*"Except in a declaration of a constructor, destructor, or conversion function, at least one defining-type-specifier that is not a cv-qualifier shall appear in a complete type-specifier-seq or a complete decl-specifier-seq."*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type#3). But it isn't depicted in the grammar, as far as I can tell. So maybe it *could* appear in the expression? I'm lost.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I'm pretty sure that's a typo, meant to say "... in a complete **defining**-type-specifier-seq ..." instead (since *type-specifier-seq* cannot produce a *defining-type-specifier* at all).

Comment: @HighCommander4 - The same typo is in the DR resolution. Could it really pass like that into the draft unchanged?

Comment: @StoryTeller: It looks like the DR resolution updated *type-specifier* in that sentence to be *defining-type-specifier*, but didn't update *type-pecifier-seq* to be *defining-type-specifier-seq*. It looks like an omission to me (in part because I can't make sense of the alternative).

Comment: @HighCommander4 - One last question out of morbid curiosity... Does `struct A* b = (1 == 1) ? (new struct A) : (new struct A);` suffer it too? (I like these odd corner cases. Good find).

Comment: @jww: The parentheses are enough to disambiguate - in fact, just parenthesizing the middle expression is enough. It's the naked `struct A :` token sequence that confuses the parser into thinking you're declaring a struct with a base clause. (The credit for finding the corner case is not mine, it goes to the user who filed [this Eclipse CDT bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526134).)

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have an authoritative answer, I have an educated guess to offer.

The *defining-type-specifier* production was added to the standard fairly recently: if you look at a [draft from late 2015](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf), it's not there, and prior to its introduction, *type-specifier* **did** have *class-specifier* as one of its alternatives.

The [change](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/efdf8b55a6c064ff615372c526e549d538bec6b8) that introduced the *defining-type-specifier* production was the resolution of [DR 2141](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2141), which concerns - wait for it - an ambiguity involving a *new-expression* with an *elaborated-type-specifier* (though it doesn't mention *conditional-expression*s specifically).

Clang's [implementation status](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html) for DR 2141 is currently listed as "Unknown".

So, my educated guess is:

- Clang and GCC do not yet implement the resolution of DR 2141

  - **Update**: I found a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50169) on the subject, and filed a [Clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34993).
- They are therefore trying to parse a *new-type-id* based on the old *type-specifier* production, which includes a *class-specifier* as one of its alternatives.

One thing I'm still a bit confused about is: even if trying to parse a *class-specifier* fails, why not backtrack and try to parse an *elaborated-type-specifier* instead? Presumably that sort of thing is necessary to disambiguate *class-specifier* and *elaborated-type-specifier* to begin with in contexts where either is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `struct` is same as `class`, just with the initial scope assumed `public:` instead of `private:`. So, once you declared `struct A {};` expressions refering to the type should use the type identifier `A` only, without the `struct` keyword:

```
A* b = (1 == 1) ? new A : new A;
```

**EDIT**

As OP noted in the comment, `struct A` is a valid type name and as such it can appear as a parameter to `new`. However, the *type-id* in `new` expression is said to be greedy. Here is an example from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

```
new int + 1 // syntactically okay, '+1' offsets the pointer returned by 'new int'
new int * 1 // error, type (int *) is assumed and 1 doesn't make sense in '(new (int *)) 1'
```

So when compiler founds a colon after `class A` it probably supposes the full declaration syntax (`class A : public base_class`) which appears incomplete *and* is not allowed here – hence the `error: redefinition of 'A'` message.

Solution: explicitly delimit the type by enclosing it in parentheses:

```
1 ? new (struct A) : new struct A;
```

Note the second `struct A` doesn't cause any problem as it is followed by a semicolon, not a colon, hence it needn't be parenthesised.

Comment: If by "should" you mean that's what you recommend as a matter of style, then I agree with you, but that's not relevant to my question. If you mean referring to the type as `struct A` is invalid, then that's incorrect; C++ allows referring to the type as `struct A`, and in most contexts it's equivalent to using just `A`.